# How to fetch profile picture from facebook javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I am trying to fetch profile picture from facebook. Right now I am getting all information from facebook but unable to get profile pic of the user. Here is my code:

```
function getFBData () {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      fbinfo = new Array();
      fbinfo[0] = response.id;
      fbinfo[1] = response.first_name;
      fbinfo[2] = response.last_name;
      fbinfo[3] = response.email;
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function (response) {
         var im = document.getElementById("profileImage").setAttribute("src", response.data.url);
         alert(im);
        });
```

How can I get picture from response of this API.

Comment: Have you asked for `user_photos` permission via the scope in your FB.login()?

Comment: Also double check that `response.data.url` actually contains something before trying to insert it into the DOM.

Comment: user_photos permission is not required for the profile pic, only if you want to get access to ALL profile pics and all albums.

Comment: @LUKE Peterson, I want to fetch only current user profile pic.

Comment: @Luke Peterson I have already called the FB.login function right now I need only profile pic.

Comment: did you try console.log(response)?

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you just use the id you've already retrieved and display the image directly? Why do you need to make an extra call?

e.g

```
function getFBData () {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  fbinfo = new Array();
  fbinfo[0] = response.id;
  fbinfo[1] = response.first_name;
  fbinfo[2] = response.last_name;
  fbinfo[3] = response.email;

     var im = document.getElementById("profileImage").setAttribute("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?type=normal");
});
}
```

For example http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=normal redirects to Mark Zuck's picture

If you're having trouble log the url out to make sure you're getting a valid id back and paste the url into a browser.

Answer (score 4):

Try Like

```
FB.api("/me", {fields: "id,name,picture"}, function(response)
{

    FB.api(
            {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT pid, src_big, src_big_height, src_big_width FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="' + response.id + '" AND name = "Profile Pictures")'
            },
            function(data1) {
                alert( data1[0].src_big );
            }
    );

});
```

This will give you the Link of the image and you can use it appropriately

[One More Option](http://www.jensbits.com/2013/04/04/get-facebook-profile-picture-with-javascript-sdk/)

Comment: Your link redirect to unwanted ads page.

Comment: This is very old post, chances are there it might have removed or changed.

Answer (score 4):

@hiraa is right, but the code is missing. Here it goes

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email,picture'}, function (response) {
    var picture_url = picture.data.url;
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16839331)

Comment: @MikeT They aren't asking for clarification, they're giving credit to hiraa who said what to change but didn't provide code.

Comment: Exactly. Anyway, do you want me to change my answer?

Comment: Excellent! Works! Thanks. But the picture is tooo small, how do I get it bigger? Thanks again!

Comment: should be response.picture.data.url;

Comment: @DevRenanGaspar it's late but for bigger profile picture you can use 
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email,picture.width(500).height(500)'}, function (response) {
    var picture_url = response.picture.data.url;
});

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this and this is running successfully. Try this :

```
FB.api('/me', { fields: 'id, name, email' }, function(response) 
{
    var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
    userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name ;

});
```

Hope You got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
    var str="<img style='border: 3px solid #3a3a3a;' src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
    return str;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but the other answers are giving my website broken links (concatenating the user ID with the rest of the URL to get the image).

I found that the correct way to do this is as follows (according to the official docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/):

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/picture",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

From the official docs, the way you get the profile picture of a user

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFbUserData(){
FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
function (response) {
    document.getElementById('profilepic').innerHTML = '<img src="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/>';

}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be response.data.url....Try with response.picture.data.url

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try These Example:

```
function(){
  var url=null;
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log("getting photo")
    FB.api(
    "/me/picture",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
      console.log(response);
      url=response.data.url;
      console.log(url);
    }else {
      console.log("Error Occured");
    }
    }
);
  }
});
  return url;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instruction from this link > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

when you try to get response from profile by default you gonna get only `id` and `name`

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response);
});
```

but if you want to get `email` and `picture` you need to add parameter like this

```
FB.api('/me' {fields: "id, name, email, picture"}, function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response);
});
```