# Get FB user's profile image- without FB login (like Pinterest on their login button)

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, pinterest

Pinterest displays your FB photo on their login/register button before you login/authorize FB. How is that possible? There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with "Check Login Status" or any other feature of their JS SDK.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#loginbutton offers a button size "Pinterest" - but when I chose that, it doesn’t show the login button any more. My guess would be that this is something special Facebook has implemented for Pinterest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here can be some useful material https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus
:)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no mention of retrieving a user's photo until after they've logged in.

Comment: `function getFBData () {
FB.api('/me', function(response) { var im = document.getElementById("profileImage").setAttribute("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?type=normal"); }` Maybe this.. Trying to help .-. font: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033964/how-to-fetch-profile-picture-from-facebook-javascript-sdk